# How to mention the author of an artistic infographic?

Tags: copyright, drawing, information-graphics, art, chart-design

I realized an "artistic page" for a social campaign which has been published on the webpage of an association. 
The project was realized through Photoshop and Illustrator and what I gave to the association is a pdf file.

My artistic page consists of a series of "boxes" placed on a colored background; each box consists of a character designed and drawn by me and a balloon with a piece of text (the text was provided by the association); basically, they are cartoons.
In other terms, I did the following:

- I planned the structure of the infographic (I decided 
  what to place, how and where in the "artistic page", I 
  choose the colors and so on);
- I designed and drew the characters;
- I designed and drew the font for the title;
- I designed and drew balloons to insert the text into them (the text wasn't mine).

My artistic page has been published on a page of their website and is taking up almost the whole space in the body of that page.

The association wants to thank me for my service, and they asked to tell them how they should mention me but I'm confused: what I did is not just drawing, but I'm not sure it may be considered graphic design.
Maybe "Art by (my nickname)"? ... Or "Graphic and Art: (my Nickname)"? Or maybe "Design:(my nickname)"...

So my question is:

How to mention the author of drawings and infographic of an artistic page for a website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Illustration by.." or "Artwork by..".

And forget about your nickname: assuming with the author caption you want people to reach you for paid work, use your real name.